# Iptables is slowing down website

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, centos7

`IPtables` is slowing down my gitlab instances. Clicking on Project or refreshing the page is taking so long (almost 30 seconds to 60 seconds). If I flush the `IPtables` list then the page refreshes within seconds.

The list is very small but I'm not sure why its slowing down.

Is there anything that I can do to improve the speed?

Here are my rules:

```
root@hostname ~]# iptables -L --line-numbers -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
1    ACCEPT     all  --  10.10.20.0/24        0.0.0.0/0
2    ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  x.x.x.x              0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
4    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8080
5    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
6    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
7    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1234
8    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1235
9    DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:1236

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
num  target     prot opt source               destination
```

iptables-save output:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jun 28 14:37:15 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [10621:23037348]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12051:23280396]
-A INPUT -s 10.10.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1235 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1236 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 28 14:37:15 2020
```

Comment: Rest of the chain is empty. Updated the output

Comment: Please add the output of `iptables-save` to your question.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen updated

Comment: Do you really mean to manually create a stateless firewall? This is rarely a good idea, especially if you aren't familiar with how iptables works. Much better to use firewalld to get everything right.

Comment: I don't know what the DROP rules are there for but they also affect localhost traffic which may be bad in some cases. Try to add a rule which accepts all traffic on `lo` interface at the beginning of INPUT chain, it just may do the trick (try `iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT` as the first rule in INPUT chain). And the DROP rules may be folded into one with multiport `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 8080,22,25,1234:1236 -j DROP`.

Comment: That did the trick. Adding loopback interface fixed the issue. I guess we always have to add loopback interface unless there is another option?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Tomek. Adding loopback interface to the top of the chain fixed the issue.

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

The final iptables-save output looks like the following:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jun 28 14:37:15 2020
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [10621:23037348]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12051:23280396]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.10.20.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s x.x.x.x/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1234 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1235 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1236 -j DROP
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 28 14:37:15 2020
```